# Passing a function over network in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Suppose the following:

I have a type called `World` representing some simulation state. I also have this type synonym:

```
type Update = World -> World
```

Is Haskell capable of serializing the Update type such that it can be passed over the network? Or is there any other means of doing so? Maybe I'm not looking for a serialization of the code's logic so much, as some kind of pointer or identifier that can be read on the other end. Both the sending and receiving process are running the same Haskell program.

Comment: You should look into 'cloud haskell' which is basically a system for passing pointers to functions assuming each side has a matching binary.

Comment: Consider making a data structure `data Event = Thing | Thing2 Int | ...`  to represent the atomic events that can happen, then a function `update :: Event -> World -> World`. You can serialize the plain data `Event` type and pass that around (and add logging etc if you like) and then use the `update` function at each end of the network connection.

Comment: Sadly, in general the answer is no.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [distributed-process](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributed-process) package is exactly what you described. Since each program already has the same set of functions a pointer to the function is passed from one process to another.  There has been mentioned serialization of the function as a potential future goal but is sound like it might take a change to GHC. The [github page](https://github.com/haskell-distributed) is a good resource for what backends exist.  The [github-pages](http://haskell-distributed.github.io/) look very nice with some examples, but I did not know about it until a moment ago.

The few Haskell Parallel digests around [issue 11](http://www.well-typed.com/blog/68) is where I remember learning the most. Definitely take some time to explore [github-pages](http://haskell-distributed.github.io/) I know I will be.

If I remember correctly there are simple examples in the hackage package or on the github repo exploring work stealing vs work sharing and similar strategies.

Comment: For the curious: 'distributed-process' is the embodiment of Cloud Haskell.  Exactly why they switched names I don't know, but it's probably for the best.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest making a DSL data structure. Sadly Haskell does not have lisp's runtime compilation features, but it should be sufficient.